# Referencing a single column of a compound primary key

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table `tbl1` with this structure:

```
tbl1
  col1 int(11)
  col2 int(11)
  col3 int(11)
  primary key(col1,col2,col3)
```

I want to create a table `tbl2` which has `col1` referencing `col1` in `tbl1`

```
create table tbl2
(
  col1 int(11),
  foreign key(col1) references tbl1(col1)
)
```

MySQL throws an error150, why? Can't I reference a single column of compound primary key of a table?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: Show the SQL causing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reference a part of a compound primary key. There is no workaround. You just cannot (and shouldn't, because it makes no sense) do it.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this in mysql,if it is there can you please provide the link.

Comment: @pavi: I'm not sure, but it's obvious: foreign key should always refer to a single row. Single row is identified by a primary key. If primary key is composite, then only combination of all PK parts identifies the row uniquely.